rdp virtual channel server initialization
I'm writing a DVC (dynamic virtual channel) plug-in and server for Remote Desktop. I have the samples working, so there's:

An in-process DLL that the RDP client uses, loaded on every connection and initialized with IWTSPlugin::Initialize(). So I can start listening at this time by calling IWTSVirtualChannelManager::CreateListener()
An EXE that runs on the RDP host machine. In this case it works when I call WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx at any time.

If I want to initiate communication from the server, the above is fine - the server can open the virtual channel. In my case, I want the server to always be listening, so the client can initiate communication at any time.
What's the recommended way to do this? I'd like to avoid polling, so I'm guessing I need to respond to some kind of event that's triggered on the RDP host when a new remote desktop session is initiated? I can keep the server EXE (from step 2 above) running at all times on the RDP host, but I'm not sure what to listen for.
